# Does a flutter app need both a data model if the Notifier class has the same data defined?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am converting old code that used legacy riverpod providers to use the NotifierProviders in riverpod 2.0.

The old code has a data model in it that has all the same data elements as the NotifierProvider. When I created the NotifierProviders I didn't look at the model file to see what is contained and it had been a couple of years since I had looked.

The model has a couple of additional functions as part of the model.

So, my question is, is it proper to move the functions out of the model class and put them in the Notifier class?

Here is the model code:
// This defines the database table or document

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Event {
  final String? eventName;
  final DateTime? eventStartTime;
  final String? eventDuration;
  final DateTime? eventDate;
  final String? eventDescription;
  final String? agentId;
  final String? agencyId;


  Event(
      {this.eventName,
      this.eventStartTime,
      this.eventDuration,
      this.eventDate,
      this.eventDescription,
      this.agentId,
      this.agencyId});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'eventName': eventName,
      'eventStartTime': eventStartTime,
      'eventDuration': eventDuration,
      'eventDate': eventDate,
      'eventDescription': eventDescription,
      'agentId': agentId,
      'agencyId': agencyId,
    };
  }

  // pass in a map and get an object back
  Event.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : eventName = firestore['eventName'],
        eventStartTime = firestore['eventStartTime'].toDate(),
        eventDuration = firestore['eventDuration'],
        eventDate = firestore['eventDate'].toDate(),
        eventDescription = firestore['eventDescription'],
        agentId = firestore['agentId'],
        agencyId = firestore['agencyId'];
}
```

Here is the NotifierProvider class:

```
class Events {
  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

  Events({
    this.eventName,
    this.eventStartTime,
    this.eventDuration,
    this.eventDate,
    this.eventDescription,
    this.userId,
    this.companyId,
  });

  Events copyWith({
    String? eventName,
    DateTime? eventStartTime,
    String? eventDuration,
    DateTime? eventDate,
    String? eventDescription,
    String? userId,
    String? companyId,
  }) {
  return Events(
    eventName: eventName ?? this.eventName,
    eventStartTime: eventStartTime ?? this.eventStartTime,
    eventDuration: eventDuration ?? this.eventDuration,
    eventDate: eventDate ?? this.eventDate,
    eventDescription: eventDescription ?? this.eventDescription,
    userId: userId ?? this.userId,
    companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
  );
  }
}

class EventsNotifier extends Notifier<Events> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final eventRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('events'));

  @override
  Events build() {
    return Events(
      eventName: '',
      eventStartTime: DateTime.now(),
      eventDuration: '',
      eventDate: DateTime.now(),
      eventDescription: '',
      userId: '',
      companyId: '',
    );
  }

  String? eventName;
  DateTime? eventStartTime;
  String? eventDuration;
  DateTime? eventDate;
  String? eventDescription;
  String? userId;
  String? companyId;

  //Setters

  void updateEventname(String newEventName) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventName: newEventName);
  }

  void updateeventStartTime(DateTime newEventStartTime) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventStartTime: newEventStartTime);
  }

  void updateEventDuration(String newEventDuration) {
    state = state.copyWith(eventDuration: newEventDuration);
  }

  void updateEventDate(DateTime? newEventDate) {
    state.copyWith(eventDate: newEventDate);
  }

  void updateEventDescription(String newEventDescription) {
    state.copyWith(eventDescription: newEventDescription);
  }

  saveEvent([String? eventId]) {

    var newEvent = Events(
        eventName: eventName,
        eventStartTime: eventStartTime,
        eventDuration: eventDuration,
        eventDate: eventDate,
        eventDescription: eventDescription,
        companyId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId,
        userId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId);


    if (eventId != null && eventId != '') {
      firestoreService.saveEvent(newEvent, eventId); // Update existing event
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewEvent(false);
    } else {
      firestoreService.saveEvent(newEvent); // Create new event
    }
  }

  deleteEvent(String? eventId) {
    firestoreService.deleteEvent(eventId);
  }
}

final eventsNotifierProvider = NotifierProvider<EventsNotifier, Events>(() {
  return EventsNotifier();
});
```

I just want to do this in the proper way as it is done in industry.

Thanks for your input.